# Top Command shows empty percent in cpu usage

Tags: linux, freebsd, top-command

I set up a virtual machine with freebsd 9.3 (I also run relayd), and when I execute command top, I get the following results which is kind of wierd:

```
last pid: 22963;  load averages:  0.56,  0.20,  0.12    up 1+02:30:06  

11:39:54
139 processes: 1 running, 127 sleeping, 10 stopped, 1 zombie
CPU:     % user,     % nice,     % system,     % interrupt,     % idle
Mem: 384M Active, 331M Inact, 198M Wired, 2716K Cache, 87M Buf, 4995M Free
Swap: 4096M Total, 4096M Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
  789 root         45  20    0  1051M   343M wait    3   2:48   0.00% java
22894 _relayd       3  52    0   132M 67504K nanslp  0   1:03   0.00% relayd
22893 _relayd       3  52    0   128M 64464K nanslp  3   1:02   0.00% relayd
22892 _relayd       3  52    0   132M 68212K nanslp  3   1:01   0.00% relayd
22891 _relayd       3  52    0   132M 70368K nanslp  3   0:58   0.00% relayd
  674 root          1  20    0 12080K  1688K select  0   0:42   0.00% syslogd
  726 root          2  20    0 28904K  4844K select  0   0:23   0.00% monit
  892 pgsql         1  20    0   186M 28876K sbwait  1   0:23   0.00% postgres
  890 pgsql         1  20    0   182M 24872K sbwait  3   0:23   0.00% postgres
  891 pgsql         1  20    0   182M 24132K sbwait  2   0:20   0.00% postgres
  762 root          1  20    0 12088K  1596K select  0   0:17   0.00% powerd
22888 root          1  52    0 90356K 30196K kqread  0   0:06   0.00% relayd
  759 root          1  20    0 22264K  3764K select  2   0:05   0.00% ntpd
  779 pgsql         1  52    0   178M 17360K select  2   0:04   0.00% postgres
  816 root          1  20    0 20344K  4880K select  0   0:04   0.00% sendmail
  785 pgsql         1  20    0 37700K  7072K select  2   0:03   0.00% postgres
  784 pgsql         1  20    0   178M 18352K select  0   0:02   0.00% postgres
```

Does anybody know why CPU information shows empty percentage?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially open top, it should be empty. It fills it in on 1 second intervals by default. You should be able to hit spacebar and refresh it. You can try the -q flag to speed up top's priority to get it to refresh more frequently. Since it's running in a virtual machine, the system clock may be off and it's having trouble polling.

If your virtualization software has any add-ons for FreeBSD, you should consider installing them for a smoother experience. e.g. vmware tools